# Sort list of Object order by date

Tags: java, collections

I have the following bean definition as below,

```
Class A{
    int id
    Date date;

}

Class B{
    int id
    Date date;

}
```

I have array List as following

```
List<A> l1 = new ArrayList<A>()
l1.add(new A(1, 2014-12-12)); 
l1.add(new A(2, 2014-12-14)); 

List<B> l2 = new ArrayList<B>()
l2.add(new B(1, 2014-12-13)); 
l2.add(new B(2, 2014-12-15));
```

Another List as follows

```
List<Object> finalList = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

now is there anyway i can put object of `l1` and `l2` in the `finalList` according to the date

e.g. The finalList should be as following

```
A(1, 2014-12-12); 
B(1, 2014-12-13);
A(2, 2014-12-14);  
B(2, 2014-12-15);
```

how can I do this??

Comment: "2014-12-12" is a String (well, now w/o " " is just an error) you should create a new Date from the string using SimpleDataFormat

Comment: its a sudo code. assume its date type object

Comment: You can make your classes implements Comparable (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface so that you can override the sorting comportment and use Collections.sort() on a list of instances. Two Date can be compared using their timestamp.

Comment: could u please write some example code. then i would be easier for me to understand

Comment: yes, the way is there. But what you have tried till now and what problem are you facing?

Comment: i dont know which way to go forward. so i did not do any coding yet. caould u please point me to the right direction with some example code? thanks

Comment: Create Date objects using SimpleDataFormat and then use a Comparator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have two different classes and both having Date objects. Instead of keeping list of objects I would suggest you creating a base interface like for example:

```
interface Dated {
   Date getDate();
}
```

Make your two classes implements this interface:

```
class A implements Dated {
 int id;
 Date date;

 @Override
 public Date getDate() {
    return date;
 }
}

class B implements Dated {
  int id;
  Date date;

  @Override
  public Date getDate() {
    return date;
  }
}
```

Create a Comparator like:

```
class DatedComparator implements Comparator<Dated> {
  @Override
  public int compare(Dated o1, Dated o2) {
    return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
  }
}
```

Then you can hold a list of Dated objects:

```
List<Dated> finalList = new ArrayList<Dated>();
```

which can be easily sorted by using your comparator:

```
Collections.sort(finalList, new DatedComparator());
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's not an option for you to make the different types in your list compatible. But if odering is really your only problem here you could user an adaptive comparator for sorting:

```
class DateOrder implements Comparator<Object> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Objecto1, Objecto2) {
        return toDate(o1).compareTo(toDate(o2));
    }

    private Date toDate(Object x) {
      if (x instanceof A) {
        return ((A)x).date;
      }
      return ((B)x).date;
    }
}
```

However having several different types in a single collection is typically not a good idea. So maybe it's better to use an instance adapter (i.e. to wrappers to provide a unique interface to the logic working on that types.) In most cases this approach is more valueable on the longer term as it's not necessary to cast over and over again just to get yet another part of the data. But I don't know enough about your problem to give a clear advice.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have a class like

```
class MyClass
{
   Date date;
}
```

You can easily sort a list of "MyClass" instances by implementing Comparable interface:

```
class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass>
{
  Date date;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(MyClass o)
  {
    if (o.date.getTime() > this.date.getTime())
     return -1;
    else
     return 1;
  }
}
```

this way, if you have a list a MyClass you can sort it like

```
Collection.sort(mylist);
```

More info here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

EDIT :

Note that you can implements multiple Comparable interface with different type so that you class can be compared to other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Supose I have this bean:

```
class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    int id;
    Date date;

    public Item(int id, String date) throws ParseException {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = formatter.parse(date);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item o) {
        return this.date.compareTo(o.date);
    }
}
```

See that I implemented the java.lang.Comparable interface.
After that I just add all items in the finalList and sort the list using the sort method of java.util.Collections class like this:

```
List<Item> l1 = new ArrayList<Item>();
    l1.add(new Item(1, "2014-12-12")); 
    l1.add(new Item(2, "2014-12-14")); 

    List<Item> l2 = new ArrayList<Item>();
    l2.add(new Item(1, "2014-12-13")); 
    l2.add(new Item(2, "2014-12-15")); 

    List<Item> finalList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    finalList.addAll(l1);
    finalList.addAll(l2);

    Collections.sort(finalList);
```

You can choose not to implement the Complarable interface in your bean and use this another method:

```
Collections.sort(finalList, new Comparator<Item>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
            return o1.date.compareTo(o2.date);
        }
    });
```